# Listening to DOM changes

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I would like to do something in angular, but I don't know if there is a way to use it.

For example:

I have a screen open in 2 tabs, on that screen there is a button, which if I click on it, it shows a div. Simple.

HTML

```
<div class="card-line" *ngIf="showDiv">
      <span>show div</span>
</div>

<button (click)="showDiv()">test</button>
```

app.ts

```
showDiv = false;

showDiv() {
    showDiv = true;
 }
```

I would like when I click this button, it would show the div both on the screen that I am on and when the screen is open on the other tab. Is it possible to do this in angular? With any way to hear this change on one tab and reflect on the other tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage.

```js
showDiv = false;

toggleDiv() {
  this.showDiv = !this.showDiv;
  localStorage.setItem('showDiv', this.showDiv ? 'true' : 'false');
}

@HostListener('window:storage', ['$event'])
handleStorageEvent(event: StorageEvent) {
  console.log(event);
  if (event.key === 'showDiv') {
    this.showDiv = event.newValue === 'true';
  }
}
```

Comment: In the same tab it even works, but if I open it in an anonymous tab, it doesn't work, because it stores it in the local storage

Comment: I don't think that's possible for anonymous tab without some kind of backend with polling or WebSocket.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)**

> The Broadcast Channel API is a simple API that makes communicating
> between browsing contexts

**Try this:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  _showDiv = false;

  // Connection to a broadcast channel
  bc = new BroadcastChannel("channel");

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.bc.onmessage = ev => {
      this._showDiv = ev.data.showDiv;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    };
  }

  showDiv() {
    this._showDiv = true;
    this.bc.postMessage({ showDiv: true });
  }
}
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-listening-to-dom-changes?file=src/app/app.component.ts)